# make $().load() work in jQuery v. 3.2.1

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I know that `$(".el").load(function()...` is deprecated from version 3.0, but now i'm in a situation where I need a plugin that's using `.load` rather than `.on("load", function()`

Is there any way to allow the use of `.load(function()` in version > 3.0 without using jQuery Migrate? Also, loading another version of jQuery isn't an option either as this seems a bit over the top for a single line of code.

EDIT: as pointed out in comment, I cannot rely on changing the plugin code as i'm using wordpress and the changes will be removed when updating.

Comment: Why don't you change the plugin code?

Comment: @silentw sorry completely forgot to write - I've made an edit. I'm using wordpress and cannot rely on direct changes - sadly

Comment: Use [jQuery.migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this? Apply both jQuery version with noConflict.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 3.2.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_3.2.1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Now in your js instead of $ just use jQuery_3.2.1.

for example,

```
jQuery_3.2.1(document).ready(....)
```

By this way you won't have to change the plugin code.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but loading another version of jquery isn't an option - sorry that I didnt write it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you can opt to use [jQuery.migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate).

This plugin adds functions removed from jQuery core. This shouldn't be used in production but should be used to fix problems you are having with your scripts.

[jQuery.migrate for Wordpress](https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-migrate/)

Comment: As specified in the question - I dont want to use migrate :)